# Accessing JSON Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

Can't seem to figure out how to access a JSON object within an array in my for loop. Any help would be great. 
Json:

```
[
 {
  subject: "******",
  subscribers_primary_advisor_id: "******",
  comments_first: "******",
  created_at: "*******",
  discussion_category: "*****",
  last_comment_by: "******",
  last_comment_by_id: "*******",
  updated_at: "*******"
 },
```

Here is my php:

```
for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++){
$sql = "INSERT INTO advisor_discussion(`comment_subject`,`advisor_id`,`content`,`date_created`,`discussion_category`,`
last_comment_id`,`updated_at`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $comment_subject, $advisor_id, $content, $date_created, $discussion_category, $last_comment_id, $updated_at);

$comment_subject = $discussion['subject'][$j];
$advisor_id = $discussion['subscribers_primary_advisor_id'][$j];
$content = $discussion['comments_first'][$j];
$date_created = $discussion['created_at'][$j];
$discussion_category = $discussion['$discussion_category'][$j];
$last_comment_id = $discussion['last_comment_by_id'][$j];
$updated_at = $discussion['updated_at'][$j];

if ($stmt->execute() !== TRUE) {
  var_dump($stmt);
  die("Error inserting discussion");
}
```

}

Comment: Your JSON data contains a JavaScript array with objects, you should access each object by refering to an index in the array. So it would be $discussion[$j]['subject'] and so on. I expect that your $size variable contains count($discussion);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have parsed the JSON with json_decode function and you have multiple JS objects contained in your JSON string then perhaps instead of `$discussion['subject'][$j]` do `$discussion[$j]['subject']` .

In other words the index first and then the JS object property.

Also note that json_decode can create PHP objects too. See here about the second parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

If you do not specify that you want an associative array then you might want to try doing `$discussion[$j]->subject` instead as you will get an array of objects.

Comment: I get an undefined index when I try it both ways, so I don't think its parsing through the data in the for loop with the increment in front of it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you tried accessing it as object property? I mean like `$discussion[$j]->subject` - it might be that your JSON objects were parsed as PHP standard objects.